# Why does my postgres data disappear after loading it from a backup?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using the official Postgres docker image and I've added a shell script that should load the backup before starting the server for real (following the instructions under 'How to extend this image' on [this page](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)

My load backup script is as follows:

```
gosu postgres pg_ctl start -w -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
gosu postgres psql -d postgres -f /dump/dump.sql
gosu postgres pg_ctl stop -w -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

And then the Postgres image automatically calls `postgres` to start the server for real.

From my logs I know that the psql and the postgres commands all run fine, but when I go into psql (`docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres`), and I `\c` into the right database and `\dt` to list relations, nothing is there!

Why could this be happening?

I do get the following errors (found by `docker logs CONTAINER_ID | grep "^[A-Z]*:\s"`), but I don't know what to make of them. Does it matter if certain functions or extensions don't exist? I'm not using them in this case:

```
WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

****************************************************
WARNING: No password has been set for the database.
         This will allow anyone with access to the
         Postgres port to access your database. In
         Docker's default configuration, this is
         effectively any other container on the same
         system.

         Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set
         it in "docker run".
****************************************************
psql:/dump/dump.sql:94: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/shar
e/postgresql/9.4/extension/plpython3u.control": No such file or directory
psql:/dump/dump.sql:101: ERROR:  extension "plpython3u" does not exist
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extensi
on/plpython3u.control": No such file or directory
STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpython3u WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
ERROR:  extension "plpython3u" does not exist
STATEMENT:  COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpython3u IS 'PL/Python3U untrusted procedural
 language';
ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
psql:/dump/dump.sql:331: ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
psql:/dump/dump.sql:334: ERROR:  function cuffdiff_metadata.load_all_cuffdiff_me
tadata(text) does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
STATEMENT:  CREATE FUNCTION load_all_cuffdiff_metadata(rna_seq_root text) RETURN
S void
ERROR:  function cuffdiff_metadata.load_all_cuffdiff_metadata(text) does not exi
st
STATEMENT:  ALTER FUNCTION cuffdiff_metadata.load_all_cuffdiff_metadata(rna_seq_
root text) OWNER TO postgres;
ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
STATEMENT:  CREATE FUNCTION filter_methylation(file_name text) RETURNS void
psql:/dump/dump.sql:701: ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
psql:/dump/dump.sql:704: ERROR:  function methylation.filter_methylation(text) d
oes not exist
psql:/dump/dump.sql:897: ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
psql:/dump/dump.sql:900: ERROR:  function public.debug(text) does not exist
ERROR:  function methylation.filter_methylation(text) does not exist
STATEMENT:  ALTER FUNCTION methylation.filter_methylation(file_name text) OWNER
TO postgres;
ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
STATEMENT:  CREATE FUNCTION debug(msg text) RETURNS void
ERROR:  function public.debug(text) does not exist
STATEMENT:  ALTER FUNCTION public.debug(msg text) OWNER TO postgres;
ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
STATEMENT:  CREATE FUNCTION load_all(csv_root text) RETURNS void
psql:/dump/dump.sql:1015: ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
ERROR:  function public.load_all(text) does not exist
psql:/dump/dump.sql:1018: ERROR:  function public.load_all(text) does not exist
psql:/dump/dump.sql:1115: ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
psql:/dump/dump.sql:1118: ERROR:  function rnaseq.load_all_cuffdiff(text) does n
ot exist
psql:/dump/dump.sql:1175: ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
STATEMENT:  ALTER FUNCTION public.load_all(csv_root text) OWNER TO postgres;
ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
STATEMENT:  CREATE FUNCTION load_all_cuffdiff(cuffdiff_root text) RETURNS void
ERROR:  function rnaseq.load_all_cuffdiff(text) does not exist
STATEMENT:  ALTER FUNCTION rnaseq.load_all_cuffdiff(cuffdiff_root text) OWNER TO
 postgres;
ERROR:  language "plpython3u" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
STATEMENT:  CREATE FUNCTION load_all_voom_edger(rna_seq_root text) RETURNS void
psql:/dump/dump.sql:1178: ERROR:  function rnaseq.load_all_voom_edger(text) does
 not exist
ERROR:  function rnaseq.load_all_voom_edger(text) does not exist
STATEMENT:  ALTER FUNCTION rnaseq.load_all_voom_edger(rna_seq_root text) OWNER T
O postgres;
LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (2 seconds apart)
HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (3 seconds apart)
HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (3 seconds apart)
HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (2 seconds apart)
HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (6 seconds apart)
HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
LOG:  sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 69
DETAIL:  Process 68 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16459 of database
12141.
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ONLY histone_homer
ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
CONTEXT:  automatic analyze of table "postgres.histone.histone_homer"
LOG:  sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 69
DETAIL:  Process 68 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16468 of database
12141.
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ONLY histone_macs
ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
CONTEXT:  automatic analyze of table "postgres.histone.histone_macs"
LOG:  sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 69
DETAIL:  Process 68 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16485 of database
12141.
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ONLY macs_gene_map
ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
CONTEXT:  automatic analyze of table "postgres.histone.macs_gene_map"
LOG:  sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 69
DETAIL:  Process 68 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16543 of database
12141.
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ONLY cg_islands
ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
CONTEXT:  automatic analyze of table "postgres.methylation.cg_islands"
LOG:  sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 69
DETAIL:  Process 68 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16551 of database
12141.
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ONLY methylation
ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
CONTEXT:  automatic analyze of table "postgres.methylation.methylation"
LOG:  sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 69
DETAIL:  Process 68 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16585 of database
12141.
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ONLY rnaseq_count
ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
CONTEXT:  automatic analyze of table "postgres.rnaseq.rnaseq_count"
LOG:  received smart shutdown request
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-04-14 07:52:46 UTC
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try to install this extension before execution of the load script? Something like that:

**Dockerfile**

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-plpython3-9.4
```

**load script**

```
gosu postgres pg_ctl start -w -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
gosu postgres psql -d postgres -c "create language 'plpythonu3';"
gosu postgres psql -d postgres -f /dump/dump.sql
gosu postgres pg_ctl stop -w -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
```